# Dynamically add content to a Bootstrap panel, overflow stops working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an overflow-y style on a Bootstrap panel body. It normally works fine. In one particular area I have a panel that is dynamically populated. If that panel has more than the panel's normal size, it extends out of the screen instead of using the overflow-y CSS attribute it has.

When you resize the screen, or open the developer console (Chrome) it resizes itself properly and puts the content in the much smaller div with a scrollbar as it should.

What is the best practice method of handling dynamically added data to a Bootstrap panel that would overflow the panel, and make it so that it auto-resized the first time without having to resort to resizing your browser?

The style "overflow-y: auto" goes on the "#reportBody" as show below:

```
        <div class="panel-body" id="reportBody">
            <table class="table table-striped" id="reportDataTable">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Total Cats</th>
                    <th>Clean Cats</th>
                    <th>Unclean Cats</th>
                    <th>Old Cats</th>
                    <th>Slightly Wrinkly Cats</th>
                    <th>Historical Cats</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: I have used `style="overflow: auto"` to add scrollbars to my table that is dynamically populated. When you say you have an overflowy style, do you mean you tried this but it does not work?

Comment: I put it on the div, not the table.

Comment: I don't have the time to set up a test, but I would try something like setting the overflow to hidden and/or display to none on the panel and then after the load I would use jquery to set the overflow to auto and /or display to block.  This way the content exists in the DOM and it's width can be calculated when the css rule is applied.

Comment: I tried that too, setting the css after the data loads. It didn't alter it (I assume) because Bootstrap sets the height dynamically.